# ¿Cómo crear nuevas hojas en Google Sheets a partir de una hoja modelo, y variando datos en una celda?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

Tengo un archivo de Hoja de Cálculo en Drive.  En ella, tengo varias hojas; una de ellas es una hoja modelo, llamada "Generador".  En la hoja Generador, en la celda K3, existe una llave: si se modifica el valor de K3 toda la información de la hoja varía, ya que está amarrada mediante fórmulas (index - match, por ejemplo) al valor de esta celda.

Existe otra hoja, llamada "Lista", en la que a partir de la celda A2 y hasta la última fila con datos (lo cual puede ser variable) contendrán la lista de valores con los que la celda K3 del generador debe de actualizarse.

La idea es que, mediante un loop, la hoja "Generador" se actualice colocando el valor del registro correspondiente de la hoja "Lista", desde el registro inicial (A2) hasta el último, y en cada uno genere una copia de la hoja Generador con los datos correspondientes a su llave.  Adicionalmente, esta copia debe de llevar por nombre el valor de la celda K3 que esté actualmente.  Esto, en un nuevo libro, como solo valores.

Esto es lo que llevo actualmente:  El loop hace lo que le digo, crea copias, cambia el registro y renombra las hojas; sin embargo, no he logrado que las cree en un nuevo libro ni que lo deje como solo valores:

```
function createEmployeeSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   // Get the range of cells that store employee data.
  var ssLista = ss.getSheetByName("Lista");
  var rgEData = ssLista.getRange(2,1);
  var eData=rgEData.getValue();//número de registros
  var employeeDataRange = ssLista.getRange(2,1,eData,1);//Nombres de hoja empezando en columna 1 desde fila 2
  var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Generador');

  for (var i=0; i < employeeObjects.length; i++) {
     // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);
      // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
      // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.
        if (sheet) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + employeeObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {
           template.getRange("K3").offset(0,0).setValue(employeeObjects[i]);
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
           }
        }
  return;
  i = 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias desde ya por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una nueva hoja de cálculo puedes usar [SpreadsheetApp.create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname), luego para copiar a esta una hoja de tu hoja de cálculo usa algo como

Antes del for

```
var name = "Nombre de la nueva hoja de cálculo";
var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
```

dentro del for, en lugar de

```
template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
```

usa

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Aplicar los cambios previos
template.copyTo(newSS).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice con este código

```
hojaACopiar.setActiveSheet(hojaACopiar.getSheetByName('__nombreHojaACopiar___'), true);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
```

Ya luego le pones el valor que necesites en la celda correspondiente.