# Cómo cambiar el nombre de hoja nueva en función de una variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Intento explicar.
Soy tutor de una clase de escolares y tengo una hoja de cálculo de Google con el resultado de todos los alumnos para todas las materias.
Ahora quiero crear dentro del mismo archivo una hoja individual para cada alumno con únicamente sus notas y un espacio reservado para que cada profesor pueda poner comentarios. Así cuando me reúno con los padres de los alumnos en esa hoja individual tengo todo lo que necesito del alumno en cuestión (sus notas y los comentarios individuales de cada profesor)
Mediante un script ya he creado todas las hojas nuevas para cada alumno pero me faltan dos cosas que no consigo:

1. Quiero cambiar el nombre de cada hoja nueva creada y poner el nombre del alumno. Por ejemplo, yo tengo 30 alumnos y con el script ya he conseguido crear 30 hojas nuevas pero el nombre de cada hoja quiero que sea el del alumno, así la primera nueva hoja quiero que se llame como el primer alumno, la segunda hoja como el segundo alumno y así hasta el último.
2. Al final estoy usando la función `TRANSPOSE` para pasar las notas que están dispuestas horizontalmente en la hoja madre a disponerlas verticalmente en las treinta nuevas hojas creadas. Ahora no sé cómo llamo a las notas de los alumnos en función de la variable. Por ejemplo, con el primer alumno las materias están en la primera fila, así que con un `=TRANSPOSE(...A1:M1)` ya lo consigo pero en cada hoja necesito llamar una fila concreta. Si llamo i a la variable que va del primer al último alumno no sé cómo llamo para el primer alumno `=TRANSPOSE(...Ai:Mi)`.

No sé si me he explicado.
Cualquier duda vuelvo a explicar.
Por cierto: No tengo ni idea de programar, ni de lenguaje de programación. Lo que he conseguido ha sido viendo vídeos y recordando algo que hice de Fortran y Pascal, hace años luz.

Comment: Bienvenido. De acuerdo a [ask], las preguntas deben ser específicas, pero esta incluye dos preguntas, una sobre el nombre de las hojas y otra sobre la función trasponer. Te sugiero quitar una y publicarla como una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Relacionado [¿Cómo crear nuevas hojas en Google Sheets a partir de una hoja modelo, y variando datos en una celda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231433/65)

Comment: Relacionado [Cambiar el nombre de una hoja en función de un listado de nombres dentro del archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/353246/65) (primera cosa de las dos mencionadas en esta pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

Como imagino que tienes muchísimos alumnos, te sugiero que en lugar de utilizar la función de transposición `=TRANSPOSE()` en la hoja de cálculo de cada alumno copies las notas de cada alumno en sus respectivas hojas de forma programática (mediante `google-apps-script`).

Se supone que partes de una tabla de notas con este aspecto en una de las pestañas de la hoja de cálculo:

[image: Tabla de notas de todos los alumnos]

El ejemplo que adjunto consiste en dos funciones, la primera se utiliza en el `for-loop` de la segunda para juntar la cabecera de la tabla principal con la fila de notas de cada alumno y hacer luego la rotación de datos. Es una especie de transposición que elimina filas no necesarias.

```
function rotate(header,array) {
  const aux = [];
  for(const value of array) {
    aux.push([header[array.indexOf(value)],value]);
  }
  return aux;
}

function updateStudentGrades() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const grades = ss.getSheetByName("Notas").getRange("A1:D6").getValues();
  const header = grades[0];
  for(const row of grades.slice(1)) {
    const studentGrades = rotate(header,row);
    const name = row[0];
    const s = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    s.getRange(1,1,studentGrades.length,2).setValues(studentGrades);
  }
}
```

La segunda función se encarga de leer la tabla de notas e interpretarla para actualizar las notas de cada alumno en su hoja correspondiente.

Atención! Te sugiero que en tu código utilices [nombres de rangos](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?cbid=-1586dzdl3v9vb&src=cb&lev=answer) para hacer referencia a los rangos en lugar de usar la notación A1 (`"A1:D6"`). Para ello tendrías que modificar el ejemplo:

```
const grades = ss.getSheetByName("Notas").getRange("NOTAS").getValues();
```

Entendiendo que el string `"NOTAS"` és el nombre que usas para el rango de datos que contiene la tabla de notas.