# Cambiar el nombre de una hoja en función de un listado de nombres dentro del archivo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Soy tutor de una clase de escolares y tengo una hoja de cálculo de Google con el resultado de todos los alumnos para todas las materias.
Ahora quiero crear dentro del mismo archivo una hoja individual para cada alumno con únicamente sus notas y un espacio reservado para que cada profesor pueda poner comentarios. Así cuando me reúno con los padres de los alumnos en esa hoja individual tengo todo lo que necesito del alumno en cuestión (sus notas y los comentarios individuales de cada profesor). 
Mediante un script ya he creado todas las hojas nuevas para cada alumno pero me faltan dos cosas que no consigo. Una de ellas es:

Quiero cambiar el nombre de cada hoja nueva creada y poner el nombre del alumno. Por ejemplo, yo tengo 30 alumnos y con el script ya he conseguido crear 30 hojas nuevas pero el nombre de cada hoja quiero que sea el del alumno, así la primera nueva hoja quiero que se llame como el primer alumno, la segunda hoja como el segundo alumno y así hasta el último.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta. Si requieres algo más específico, agrega una versión simplicada de tu script (usualmente lo referimos como [mcve]) a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Usa [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename) donde `name` es una variable que hace referencia a un valor tipo `string` que en este caso sería el nombre del alumno.

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo crear nuevas hojas en Google Sheets a partir de una hoja modelo, y variando datos en una celda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231433/65)

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén.